Can't join a room with custom properties using Photon Pun 2 in Unity
I made some game modes for players to play, so I want to store the room's gamemode in it's custom properties, so the players who want to play the same mode will join the same room it is full, then create a new room and fill it.
    #region Random Room Joining
    public void JoinOrCreateRandomRoom()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom(new Hashtable { { "Mode", gameMode } }, 10);
        //gameMode is a string variable containing the mode that the player wants to play.
    }

    public override void OnJoinRandomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
    {
        Debug.Log(message);

        string roomName = gameMode + Random.Range(10000, 99999);
        RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions()
        {
            IsVisible = true,
            IsOpen = true,
            MaxPlayers = 10,
            CustomRoomProperties = new Hashtable { { "Mode", gameMode } },
            CustomRoomPropertiesForLobby = new string[] { "Mode" }
        };
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(roomName, roomOptions, null);
    }
    #endregion

The debug says: "No match found" and player creates a new room instead of joining the already created one.
I expect the player to join another player with the same room custom properties.
